# Change of WAR file according to the platform on the same URL with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

We have created 2 applications: 1 application to serve PC-sized screen users and another for mobile users. Both projects will be hosted on different Tomcat instances inside a `ROOT` folder.

If we have different urls for both the applications (e.g. for **desktop** we have *www.xyz.com* and for **mobile** *m.xyz.com*) then it works very well for us.

But we don't want different domains for both. Rather, we want the same url to work for both the websites. So that according to the platform, the specific application changes but url is the same.

Like `ROOT.war` on Tomcat 1 and `ROOt.war` on Tomcat 2, they run both on same url `abc.com`. So, using the same URL for both mobile and desktop applications, but the actual application is selected based upon whether the user is mobile or not.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Meet [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Comment: I try to edit your questing, but so hard, please edit your question by yourself!

Comment: We have two different war file its not about responsiveness.

Comment: How can you tell that the user is mobile versus desktop?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need a reverse proxy in front of the two applications. It's easy to do with `httpd` and Tomcat. Here's one way you could do it:

1. Configure `httpd` to use `mod_jk` to proxy to Tomcat (in general).
2. Configure `mod_jk` with a worker for each of your applications (`desktop`, `mobile`).
3. Configure `httpd` with `mod_setenvif` to choose the worker based upon some criteria (e.g. user-agent). You can use `mod_rewrite` if you want even more complicated configuration.

   `JkWorkerIndicator JK_WORKER_NAME       ## Note this is the default`

   `SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME=desktop-worker   ## Your default site`

   `BrowserMatch "mobile" JK_WORKER_NAME=mobile-worker`

   `SetHandler jakarta-servlet             ## replaces JkMount`

This will select the worker name depending upon your criteria (looking for "mobile" in the client's `User-Agent` header in this example.

If this were my product, I'd try to build it all together in a single application with responsive design, hiding workflows that aren't appropriate for space-constrained devices.